# JQUERY not closing pop up and refreshing page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following script and its successfully removing the underlying record from the database. But on clicking the confirm, nothing happens at all. Meaning I have to close both pop ups then hit F5 on the browser to see the results. I've tried many things but must be something simple i'm missing here

```
function deletePayment(customerPaymentId) {
    //alert(customerPaymentId);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure? This payment will be logically deleted", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            var url = '/CustomerPayment/Delete';
            var data = {
                id: customerPaymentId
            };

            $.post(url, data, function () {

                window.location.reload();
            });



        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

CONTROLLER CODE BELOW:

```
//[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

//[Authorize(Roles = "Delete")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{

    CustomerPayment obj = _db.GetCustomerPayment(id);

    _db.Edit(obj);

    obj.TransactionDateTimeEnd = DateTime.Now;
    _db.Save();




    return View("Index", new { id = obj.CustomerId});
}
```

Comment: take out return false? also are you sure you're including Jquery?

Comment: take a look at the jquery docs for $.post : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

you only implement the `success` handler for $.post, so if the post fails (does not return with a 200(OK) status code), the window is never reloaded.

Comment: There is no point at all using ajax if your just intending to call `window.location.reload();` to reload the page.

Comment: Kyle, I removed the 'return false;' but its still the same. Tim, not sure what to change can you give an example please

Comment: Stephen I want the pop up from bootbox to confirm, for that i need AJAX

Comment: No you don't - you need jquery. And step logically through your code. You make a POST to the server and delete an item, but then make a call to the `Index()` method and generate its html and return it back to the client. Then you ignore all that and then use `window.location.reload()` to make another call the the `Index()` method to refresh the page (more than twice as inefficient as making a normal form submit/redirect).

Comment: But if you wanted to improve performance, then you method would return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise and just delete the associated item from the DOM without doing any page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code I have tested.

I would tell you to remove return false and make the ajax call like below having explicitly attaching success and failure callback.

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function (e) {
            bootbox.confirm("Delete payment ???", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        alert('delete fired');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "Jquery-datatable.aspx/GetJsonEmps",
                            data: "{}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert('ok');
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                            { 
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                            location.reload(); 
                            }    
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Note: I have quickly checked above example for the sake of testing.You have to replace the rquest type to `POST` and request `url` and add `data` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

## For controller

```
public JsonResult Delete(int? id)
        {           
            if (isSuccess)
                return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

## and your script add below line

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Let me know if you have any question.